# For loops program to print out a rectangle

Tags: python, for-loop, rectangles

I have a problem writing a program with for loops. I am not sure how to go about it but I first of all looped through a string containing a number. And now I need to replicate a string '#' with the individual numbers within that number e.g.  I want to replicate the string '#' by replicating it with 2 from '274878'. This is my code so far:

```
bars_string = input('Enter bars string:\n ')
print('+---------+')
for element in bars_string:
  pass
```

This is my expected output for a given number string:

```
Enter bars string:
2378945
+---------+
|##       |
|###      |
|#######  |
|######## |
|#########|
|####     |
|#####    |
+---------+
```

Comment: Break it down into pieces. Given the number `2`, do you know how to print 2 `#`s? If so, and you need to follow 9 characters total, then you know you need to also print `9 - 2 == 7` spaces after it; but if you know how to print two `#`s, you should also be able to use that knowledge to print 7 spaces.

Comment: Anyhow -- try to break the problem down into pieces, and implement each piece, and then ask about the _specific piece_ you get stuck on, instead of asking someone to just do your work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
bars_string = input('Enter bars string:\n ')
digits = list(map(int, bars_string))
max_digit = max(digits)

print("+" + "-"*max_digit + "+")
for digit in digits:
  print("|" + "#"*digit + " "*(max_digit - digit) + "|")

print("+" + "-"*max_digit + "+")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use format strings:

```
barString = "2378945"

print("+---------+")
print(*(f"|{'#'*int(n):9}|" for n in barString),sep="\n")
print("+---------+")


+---------+
|##       |
|###      |
|#######  |
|######## |
|#########|
|####     |
|#####    |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to times the `#` with the `element` in integer form. And in python, you can literally times strings with a number! Here's the code:

```
bars_string = input('Enter bars string:\n ')
#2378945
for element in bars_string:
  print('#'*int(element))
```